# How to devide matser page with update panels and validators

Tags: updatepanel

I have a master page with a left `Div` area containing a `UserControl` holding 3 `texboxes+validators` and a submit button just for inserting simple data to my DB.

In the MainContent area I have my `contentPlaceHolder` for all of my web pages. Insides those pages I have more `textboxes+validators` and another submit button.

The problem is that when I want to submit something from either the UC or from the main area pages, it seems that the validators are triggered in all of the master page areas (i.e. in the UC and in the main pages).

I know I should work with an update panel but not sure how to wrap weach part of the master page and how to configure it so it will devide the activation of the validators for each part seperately.

Thank.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set ValidationGroup of each validator to separate them to groups. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.validationgroup.aspx) example.